# Navigating to randomly generated URL only if specific class inside that page exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Ok, lets say I want to go to random page using function for generating random URL.If an image with class="hello" doesn't exist within that page,I don't load it.I use function for random URL again until I find page which contains image with class="hello".Is this possible to do?If the answer is "Yes" I would very much appreciate if you could point me to some guides for Ajax or anything required to do this.

Comment: What is : you want to go to random page? Are you talking about navigating to a page or loading the page/content using Ajax ?

Comment: I want to navigate to page.Lets say I have 3 pages called:"page1","page2" and "page3" but only 1 of them has image with class="hello".What I want to do is only navigate to the page with specified class with a click of button.

Comment: But to check whether a page has the data/class you are looking for, first you need to load the page with via Ajax call or in iframe..

Comment: Is it possible to load the page in the background if you know what I mean?Cause I want the client to be able to just click the button and wait till the page is found and only once the page has been found,the client gets navigated to that page.Hope I explained a little bit better.

Comment: Yup.. i got that.. you can use Ajax calls for that. I vl put some code in the answer section

Comment: If you could also link some Ajax/JS guides regarding my problem would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) for your specific requirement. I am using fetch API for demo purpose.

Below is the code snippet :

```
function checkAndLoad(url) {
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'get'
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log('Response Here : ', response);
        // write your logic to check for Class/ID in HTML and navigate
        // window.location = url;
    }).catch(function(err) {
       // Error :(
    });
}

checkAndLoad('https://jsonblob.com/c089bff7-073a-11e7-a0ba-41ab99606d1f');
```